# Overload depending on result of lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have a class like:

```
class foo
{
    EventManager<LRESULT(UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)> Events;

    template<typename T>
    void addListener(int e, T&& lambda) { events.add(e, lambda); }
};
```

However, I need to accept TWO types of lambdas. One with the signature:

`[&](UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM) -> LRESULT {}` and one with the signature: `[&](UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM) -> void {}`.

So I want to determine the return type of the lambdas..

I tried something like:

```
template<typename T>
void addListener(int e, T&& listener)
{
    if (std::is_void<decltype(listener(0, 0, 0))>::value)
    {
        Events.Subscribe(e, [&](UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) -> LRESULT {
            listener(msg, wp, lp);
            return DefWindowProcW(this->Handle(), msg, wp, lp);
        });
    }

    Events.Subscribe(e, [&](UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) -> LRESULT {
        std::function<LRESULT()> func = std::bind(listener, msg, wp, lp);
        return func();
    });
}
```

I also tried declaring the function as a template with the following signature:

`template<typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_void<typename std::result_of<T(UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)>::type>::value>::type>`

to overload it but it doesn't work either..

Any ideas what I can do without having to create two methods (one for each signature)?

Comment: An unrelated design question: Why limit yourself to only "lambdas" (and global/namespace/static member functions)? Why not use `std::function` instead so you can have more types of listeners (like `std::bind` objects)?

Comment: As for your problem, why not overload the function, one that takes an argument returning `void` and another that takes an argument returning `LRESULT`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I doubt it is limited to lambdas, since you can't store them as such.

Comment: I tried to overload it. It is ambiguous. I did:  `void addListener(int, std::function<void(args)> &&f)` and `void addListener(int, std::function<LRESULT(args)> &&f)`. Both ambiguous in 4.8.1

Comment: Btw, msvc?  If so mention it: msvc's implementation of SFINAE is missing what they call 'expression SFINAE'.  Or, in short, is not conforming.

Comment: @Brandon you should probably not capture the `listener` *by reference* in a lambda expression `[&]` - it might be a prvalue temporary ending its lifetime after the call to `addListener`

Comment: Yeah. I noticed. I ended up capturing it with `[=]` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Option #1

Dispatch the call to a proper overload:

```
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

class foo
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    void addListener(int e, T&& listener)
    {
        addListener(e, std::forward<T>(listener), std::is_void<decltype(listener(0, 0, 0))>{});
    }

private:
    EventManager<LRESULT(UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)> Events;

    template <typename T>
    void addListener(int e, T&& listener, std::true_type)
    {
        Events.Subscribe(e, [=](UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) -> LRESULT {
            listener(msg, wp, lp);
            return DefWindowProcW(this->Handle(), msg, wp, lp);
        });
    }

    template <typename T>
    void addListener(int e, T&& listener, std::false_type)
    {
        Events.Subscribe(e, [=](UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) -> LRESULT {
            std::function<LRESULT()> func = std::bind(listener, msg, wp, lp);
            return func();
        });
    }
};
```

[**DEMO 1**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0df1b2f9cec378fc)

#### Option #2

Add overloads with a SFINAE condition (you need a dummy type template parameter `typename = void` if you want to hide the `enable_if` within a template parameters list in the second overload, to make the function templates' declarations distinct):

```
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

class foo
{
public:    
    template <typename T,
              typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_void<typename std::result_of<T(UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)>::type>::value>::type>
    void addListener(int e, T&& listener)
    {
        Events.Subscribe(e, [=](UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) -> LRESULT {
            listener(msg, wp, lp);
            return DefWindowProcW(this->Handle(), msg, wp, lp);
        });
    }

    template <typename T,
              typename = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_void<typename std::result_of<T(UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)>::type>::value>::type,
              typename = void>
    void addListener(int e, T&& listener)
    {
        Events.Subscribe(e, [=](UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) -> LRESULT {
            std::function<LRESULT()> func = std::bind(listener, msg, wp, lp);
            return func();
        });
    }

private:
    EventManager<LRESULT(UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)> Events;
};
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4ee828354339d38)

#### Option #3

Use a trailing return type with a `decltype()` specifier to enable/disable overloads:

```
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

class foo
{
public:    
    template <typename T>
    auto addListener(int e, T&& listener)
        -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_void<decltype(std::forward<T>(listener)(0, 0, 0))>{}>::type
    {
        Events.Subscribe(e, [=](UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) -> LRESULT {
            listener(msg, wp, lp);
            return DefWindowProcW(this->Handle(), msg, wp, lp);
        });
    }

    template <typename T>
    auto addListener(int e, T&& listener)
        -> typename std::enable_if<!std::is_void<decltype(std::forward<T>(listener)(0, 0, 0))>{}>::type
    {
        Events.Subscribe(e, [=](UINT msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) -> LRESULT {
            std::function<LRESULT()> func = std::bind(listener, msg, wp, lp);
            return func();
        });
    }

private:
    EventManager<LRESULT(UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)> Events;
};
```

[**DEMO 3**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e70eb39d3e2e742)